# Is there a quick way to get all statements, check images etc. from a checking account/credit card account?

Tags: united-states, bank-statements

Suppose someone has had a checking account or a credit card with a bank for many years and has opted out of paper statements. Suppose they wanted to have a record of all statements either in pdf format or paper format. They could download statements into a computer one at a time. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: That would depend 100% on the bank.

Answer (score 4):

Walk into a branch of your bank and ask for the documents that you need. I did this when I needed to show statements and transactions in court. There was a printing fee for large page counts. What is available, how much it costs, and how long it takes will vary by bank.

If you are unfamiliar enough with your bank's web site or programming API that you ask people who don't know your bank how to do this, it will be quicker to ask the bank to prepare the documents than to learn to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who has experience with programming, I would say that it's 100% depending on whether the bank has any publicly available [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface?wprov=sfla1).

If you'll tell us which bank you have in mind, it'll be easier to give a more definitive answer.